# Populate ListView from Indexdb

Tags: javascript, winjs, indexeddb, windows-8.1

I'm working with windows 8.1 winJS, and trying to populate listView from indexedb and can't make it work.
I am getting a string from jsonStr line 76 but I'm not able to bind to the html.

MY javascript

```
(function () {

"use strict";

var nav = WinJS.Navigation;
var session = WinJS.Application.sessionState;
var util = WinJS.Utilities;

WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExampleA",
    {
        itemList: new WinJS.Binding.List()
    })

var plantsData1 = [

{ id: 1, title: "Banana blast1", text: "Ice cream", picture: "images/plants/Acalypha pendula.jpg" },
{ id: 2, title: "Banana blast2", text: "Ice cream", picture: "images/plants/Acalypha pendula.jpg" },
{ id: 3, title: "Banana blast3", text: "Ice cream", picture: "images/plants/Acalypha pendula.jpg" }
];

var indexedDB = window.msIndexedDB;
var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction;

if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.console.log("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.")
}

var db;
var request = window.msIndexedDB.open("plantsDatabase", 1);

request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log("error: ");
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    db = request.result;
    console.log("success: " + db);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    console.log('Creating object stores');
    var db = event.target.result;
    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("plantsStore", { keyPath: "id" });
    for (var i in plantsData1) {
        objectStore.add(plantsData1[i]);
    }
}

function read() {
    var transaction = db.transaction(["plantsStore"]);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("plantsStore");
    var request = objectStore.get("00-03");
    request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log("Unable to retrieve daa from database!");
    };
    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        // Do something with the request.result!
        if (request.result) {

            // console.log("Name: " + request.result.name + ", Age: " + request.result.age + ", Email: " + request.result.email);
        } else {
            console.log("Kenny couldn't be found in your database!");
        }
    };
}

function buttonreadAll(plantsBind) {
    var transaction = db.transaction(["plantsStore"]);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("plantsStore");


    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {

            var plantsBind = cursor.value;
            var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(plantsBind);
            console.log(jsonStr);
            var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(cursor.value);
            // Create a namespace to make the data publicly accessible. 
            var publicMembers =
                {
                   itemList: dataList

                };
            WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExampleA", publicMembers);

            cursor.continue();
        }
        else {
            console.log("No more entries!");
        }
    };
}



WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/hub/hub.html", {
    processed: function (element) {
        return WinJS.Resources.processAll(element);
    },

    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {

        var readAll = document.getElementById("readAll");
        readAll.addEventListener("click", buttonreadAll, false);

    },


    unload: function () {
        // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.
    },

    updateLayout: function (element) {
        /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />

        // TODO: Respond to changes in layout.



    },
});




})();
```

and my html

```
<div class="section3" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.HubSection" data-win-options="{ isHeaderStatic: true }" data-win-res="{ winControl: {'header': 'Section3'} }">
                  <div id="IconTextTemplate1" class="win-container win-itembox win-item" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                    <div style=" padding: 5px; overflow: hidden; display: -ms-grid;">
                        <img data-win-bind="alt: title; src: picture" src="#" style="width: 80%;  margin-left: 10%; margin-right:10%; margin-bottom:2%; -ms-grid-column: 1;" />
                        <div style="margin: 15px; -ms-grid-row: 2">
                            <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h3>
                            <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: picture"></h3>
                            <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: text"></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                     data-win-options="{
                     itemDataSource : DataExampleA.itemList.dataSource,
                     itemTemplate: select('#IconTextTemplate1'),
                     layout : {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}">
                </div> 
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Kristof's response, you want to replace this code:

```
var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(cursor.value);
// Create a namespace to make the data publicly accessible. 
var publicMembers =
    {
    itemList: dataList

};
WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExampleA", publicMembers);
```

With just this line, because you've already created a List:

```
DataExampleA.itemList.push(cursor.value);
```

I tried this out in a project and it worked just fine.

The question is then how to get the ListView to update itself when you add something to the database. The answer there is that if you add an item to DataExampleA.itemList, to which the ListView is bound, that will update the ListView. This means that you'll need to have a routine that updates the list whenever the db is changed, basically maintaining the two in parallel while the app is running. When the app is restarted, of course, you'd reinitialize the Binding.List from the db so they start in sync.

The other approach you can take is to create a custom data source on top of the IndexedDB, which you do by implementing an object with some part of the [IListDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212603.aspx) interface methods, then use that to create a [WinJS.UI.VirtualizedDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701413.aspx). This is a little more work, but will scale better if you anticipate a large data set. For more on this, see Chapter 7 of my [second preview ebook (free)](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), in the section "Collection Control Data Sources."

Comment: **love you book**, it is so nice explain. I have other question how i can refresh listView because it adding some data again when i click buttonreadAll(), thaks

Comment: If you have a ListView bound to a WinJS.Binding.List, then adding items to the List will trigger a refresh in the ListView. That's what I was trying to say above by keeping your db and List object in sync.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT tnx for sharing. I'll take a look at it and look how I can plug it into my framework.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new list for every item you retrieve.

Use the push method to add new items to the listview collection.

I'm not a 100% sure this will work. I've tried this too a while a go and didn't work the way I wanted. I believe the issue I had was that events weren't triggered when I add data and that way they didn't get visualised.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a global db variable.